# Вопрос по LESS. Есть ли конструкция аналогичная SCSS?

Tags: less

В SCSS есть такая конструкция

```
.item {
    .sublist & {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Что преобразуется в CSS в

```
.sublist .item {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Есть ли похожая конструкция в LESS? Как записывается? Изучал https://lesscss.org/, но не увидел ничего похожего

Comment: Вот например плейграунд для less - https://lesscss.org/less-preview/ . Напишите там вашу конструкцию и увидите что в less это тоже работает.

Answer (score 0):

В общем в LESS она выглядит аналогично

```
.item {
    .sublist & {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Спасибо  [Pavel Grishaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/347472/pavel-grishaev) !